# How to put navbar in this position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't make a navbarmenu fit in the web position, I tried so many times but didn't work for me.
Could someone help me please.

How can i make this navbar in this position : https://prnt.sc/pMAPPMmneH7x
navbar in the photo.

In this case i used  : display: flex;

align-items: center;

justify-content: space-between;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: question is not clear ? do u want fit like the image ?

Comment: Yes @A.J i want to fit my navbar like in the image.

Comment: @florinbroqi , u can use bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#how-it-works).

Comment: @florinbroqi: What attempt have you made?  What didn't work as expected in that attempt?  The question includes a handful of CSS rules which would be useful in implementing this.  What happens when you try?  Please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates what you tried and what isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I would do it ( If you have any questions, feel free to ask! ) :

```css
/* Bright Colors are for debug !!! */


/* Setting font and variable that will be used everywhere */
:root {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  --dev-color: #5faedb;
}

/* Making sure the page cannot scroll left to right, only top to bottom */
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Styling the navigation bar to contain 3 elements, .branding, .links, and .auth, */
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--dev-color);
  position: fixed;
}

/* Styling container where logo is stored and styled */
.nav>.branding {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav>.branding>a,
.nav>.branding>a>img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Un-Ordered list of links ( Navigation ) */
.nav>.links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav>.links>li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav>.links>li>a {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav>.links>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav>.links>li>a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

/* Authentication links ( Usually Sign in and Sign up ) */
.nav>.auth {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav>.auth>a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Your Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav" id="nav">
    <span class="branding">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="#">
          <img
            src="https://www.kadencewp.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/alogo-1.png"
            alt="Brand Logo"
          />
        </a>
      </span>
    <ul class="links">
      <!-- Links inside of navigation bar -->
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Authentication Links -->
    <span class="auth"><a href="#" class="signup">Sign Up</a></span>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

In your `<header>` tag create 3 tags and then use flexbox.

For instance:

```css
header {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>My Logo</a>
  <nav>
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <a>Link 3</a>
  </nav>
  <button>Sign Up</button>
</header>
```

Now it should work!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, the flex property will also work there, I just edited the answer.